# How to handle connection switch while there is a OnGoing Request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, elasticsearch

Good morning !!
I am currently writing a Node.js script which is contacting a elastic cluster to get some data.

Well script does run smoothly.. I am using Mac.

Now I came over a scenario where when my script is running my WiFi is getting switched from one connection to another connection , whenever this happens my script hangs.

How can I handle these scenario in node.js for retrying that particular request.

I am using request module and node v6+.

Whenever I try to reproduce this error. My script hangs for long time and not throwing any error.

P.S: I am already retrying for 'ETIMEDOUT', 'ECONNREFUSED', 'ENETUNREACH'

Update 1:

```
const request = require('request');
const co = require('co');

function _makeRequest(options) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) return reject(error);
      return resolve(body);
    });
  })
}

function makeRequest() {
  let esOptions = { 
    method: 'GET',
    url: `http://www.google.com`
  };
  return _makeRequest(esOptions);
}


co(function *() {

  let result = yield makeRequest();

  console.log(result);

}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
})
```

To reproduce the issue i am facing, just use the above script and with wifi connection 
1. First without any tweaks it will print the html in console.
2. Now start the script as soon it start the switch your wifi-connection to some other network and wait (For me it does not throw any timeout error OR any kind of error in console).

Comment: you are using any socket io in your code ? or your code stops at particular point ?

Comment: Nope. Just request is on going .

Comment: its strange, switching wifi may affect only part where request is sent and not on entire code. Can you confirm send request is blocked ?

Comment: How can I confirm because the request module is not timing out or throwing error

Comment: you should narrow down for issue. Normally every app has this flow send request -> get response -> do some processing. You should find out at what step issue is there. Are you sending requests in loop ?

Comment: Yes. But the thing is one only request made.. meantime my WiFi connection got switched now that request didn't end or timeout or didn't throw error.. it just hangs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an underlying dependency upon TCP for your HTTP request.  When your Mac switches which wifi network its associated with, you are breaking the established TCP connection (without the ends gracefully negotiating termination of the connection via RST packets).  That established TCP connection then enters an idle but keep_alive state, which on most Linux or Macs will by default be about 2 hours before such idle connections are pruned.

(You can check your Mac's defaults (in ms) through:

```
# sysctl net.inet.tcp | grep keep
net.inet.tcp.keepidle: 7200000
net.inet.tcp.keepintvl: 75000
net.inet.tcp.keepinit: 75000
net.inet.tcp.keepcnt: 8
net.inet.tcp.always_keepalive: 0
```

)

So, as you've discovered, you won't automatically get that much notification from the established-but-idle TCP connection (propagated from the network layer) that was broken ; you might be able to create another event to re-trigger your re-try logic through use of some of the npm modules that aim to manage wifi-based networks?

I'd suggest you google `npm wifi` and see if any of the packages suggested is suitable for your circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I couldn't find any exact module for this i suppose I am going to ask Node.js Team itself.

Comment: The networking abstraction is well below the node.js layer being managed by the OS; so, I suspect that you'll not get a solution directly.

I'm surprised you felt you couldn't use some of the existing 'wifi'-related modules : I thought what you would need could well be constructed from an npm module such as `wifi-control`, although other options certainly exist.  It looked to me the basic tracking of successful connections, timeouts, and re-establishing connections that you could wrapper into an application registered callback to re-init your request on an interval basis or your choice...